# how to reconstruct the original Image after modification using SVD

Tags: matlab, svd, decomposition, data-hiding

I have decomposed my image using `svd` and modified the singular values by adding matrix, let's say `A`. How can I get back this matrix `A`.

For example:

```
 m=[1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
 [u s v]= svd(m);
 A=[0 2 1; 3 5 6; 8 9 4];
 sw= s+A;
 new= u*sw*v;
```

Now how can I get back my matrix `A` from matrix `new`?

Answer (score 1):

To reconstruct `A` from its SVD given by `u`, `s`, `v` you would use

```
m_rec = u*s*v';
```

So in your case just replace `s` by `sw`:

```
m_rec = u*sw*v';
```

That is, you're only missing a conjugate transpose (`'`) in your matrix `new`.

However, the modification you apply to `s` seems to be too large, and it's not even diagonal, so you are not going to reconstruct `m` properly. You would if the modification were small. For example:

```
>> sw = s + diag(.1*randn(1,3));
>> m_rec = u*sw*v'
m_rec =
    0.9987    1.9977    3.0348
    4.0070    5.0543    6.0256
    7.0533    8.0348    9.0543
```

Comment: Thank you Luis Mendo,  for your kind reply, Actually i want to get matrix "A", from the matrix "new".

Comment: @user3327980 In your matrix "new" you need to replace `v` by `v'`.

Comment: okay new=u*sw*v'; Now how can i get matrix A..? kindly reread my example.. m=[1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
 [u s v]= svd(m);
 A=[0 2 1; 3 5 6; 8 9 4]; 
 sw= s+A;
 new= u*sw*v';  Now I want to get matrix "A" from matrix "new"... Is thr any way kindly help me out

Answer (score 0):

There is a misunderstanding afoot. The matrix of singular values for a matrix of rank rho has the properties (1) it is diagonal like and (2) the singular values are ordered such that *s*<sub>1</sub> >= *s*<sub>2</sub> >= *s*<sub>3</sub> >= ... *s*<sub>rho</sub> > 0. The matrix addition you describe violates both principles.

To amplify, if you perturb the matrix of singular values you must not include off-diagonal entries and you must preserve Archimedean ordering. When the matrix A in line three is added to the matrix s the resultant matrix is not a matrix of singular values.